# Use a custom input field for search with GCS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use the google custom search, but I want to search through my search box, not the search box provided by GCS

```
<div class="android-search-box mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-textfield--align-right mdl-textfield--full-width">
    <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" for="search-field">
        <i class="material-icons">search</i>
    </label>
    <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
        <form method="get">
            <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text"id="search-field">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the difference between your search box and GSC?

Comment: I need my search box due to some customization, is it possible to do that?